# What is the correct input type for credit card numbers?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

**TLDR:** Which input type can utilize the mobile numeric keyboards AND implement masking with spaces injected and a max limit for CVV and Credit Card inputs, such as: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX

---

When building forms, I have seen a varied degree of consistency surrounding the correct input type for credit cards. Here are my discovered pros and cons for each:

**type=text**

- Able to mask easily with various libraries such as cleave.js or set maxLength attribute
- Mobile users do not receive numeric-only keyboard, unless setting range to [0-9] (Only iOS users will get this experience, leaving Android users with full keyboard)

**type=number**

- Proper keyboard shown on iOS and Android but unwanted characters can be entered and no maxLength can be set. Min and Max do not limit users from inputting more than 16 characters but do provide error messages when over the max. *Note, this input type is basically ruled out due to leading 0's being deleted. (Unacceptable for CVV's)

**type=tel**

- Able to properly mask and is utilized all over the place, BUT may have unknown impacts on accessibility programs and autofillers. If anyone can provide clarification on the potential side effects of using this input type, that would be awesome!

These are all the types that came to mind. If anyone has any other recommendations, please let me know!

Comment: Use type is text is best method and i suggest you to use this validator for perfect credit card validation. http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/#supported-cards

Comment: That is actually the validator I am using. The problem with type=text is that your won't get the mobile experience like I described.

Answer (score 35):

### HTML

If you're trying to do this strictly with HTML, I believe the following is going to get you about as close as is currently possible:

```html
<form>
  <label for="ccn">Credit Card Number:</label>
  <input id="ccn" type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9\s]{13,19}" 
         autocomplete="cc-number" maxlength="19" 
         placeholder="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" required>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

- `inputmode` sets the keyboard type (in this case, numeric)
- `pattern` enables validation (in this case, numbers and spaces with a length of between 13 and 19) and it helps with keyboard type for browsers that don't yet support `inputmode`
- `autocomplete` tells browser what should be autocompleted (in this case, a credit card number)
- `maxLength` prevents the user from entering more than the set number of characters (in this case, 19, to include numbers and spaces)
- `placeholder` gives the user an example (formatting hint)

### JavaScript

For a more robust solution, JavaScript is going to be required. And rather than roll your own solution, it'd probably be best to use a battle-tested library. [Cleave.js](https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js) (as you mentioned) is a popular choice.

Comment: This is a great write up of probably the best you can do today. It just seems a bit strange that an input mode for something so commonly used is still subject to possible side effects due to the tel input type.

Comment: Cleave was updated to [cleave-zen](https://github.com/nosir/cleave-zen) Cleave.js is now deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I’ve seen using `type="tel"` on many places, for the reasons you mention.

I would not recommend `type="number"` as then you have to fiddle with in/decrement arrows etc. And from certain point of view it is not a “number” in terms of what we usualy do with numbers (maths), see [this comment on CSS tricks forum](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/html5-input-types-for-credit-card-numbers/#post-146376).

Another trick how to force numeric keyboard is using `pattern="[0-9]*"`. This [should work on iOS only](https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/). To make it work on Android as well, you have to combine it with the `type="tel"`.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I still think there should be a better standard for developers given how common this input field is.

Comment: I think there is, but not widely supported. It is the new attribute `inputmode`. In this case the mark-up would be following (simplified): `<input type="text" inputmode="numeric">`. See the further info [in the CSS tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/#article-header-id-2).

Answer (score 3):

There's an attribute `inputmode` that's designed for that, it's not implemented yet (actually deprecated in HTML 5.2), but there's work done on it (FF/Chrome).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

And see this discussion: 
https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3290

For now set the autocomplete attribute to the correct value: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill

or implement a customized input with mask like you're using now.

Comment: So you would recommend using type=tel and specifying the autofill attribute? Do you think there would be any side effects?

Comment: Is it really deprecated? It is a living standard now. I think we can use it now at 2022.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-inputmode