# Is there a way to format the input field for credit card info without using javascript?

Tags: html, css, forms, accessibility

I mean the input field needs to be formatted in numeric sets of four digits with a space in between. I know a bunch of javascript plugins that do it but this is an accessibility issue and I'm surprised that this requirement hasn't been considered by web standards yet.

[image: credit card formatting]

I have the following input field with some CSS to start with… if it helps or if someone has been down this path before:

```css
form.order>input.card {
  border: 0;
  padding: 2.5vmin 5vmin;
  border-radius: 10vmin;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #111111;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 60vmin;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<form class="order">
  <input class="card" type="number" placeholder="xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct input type for credit card numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534229/what-is-the-correct-input-type-for-credit-card-numbers)

Comment: No it doesn't. Input type is different from formattability of an input field. This is a CSS issue rather than datatype.

Comment: Why do you believe this is an accessibility issue (I can understand plugins causing issues but JavaScript itself is an issue?)? I am assuming you want live groupings as you type or can they be grouped on `blur` for your needs? Is the requirement for no JavaScript purely that you have had bad experiences with plugins adding random characters?

Comment: http://filamentgroup.github.io/politespace/demo/demo.html i.e. would this be suitable for your needs (as a base / concept, it needs a few improvements, I mean is the concept suitable for your needs), it only formats the data on blur so is unobtrusive.

Comment: It is hard to see the inputted numbers unless they are grouped in sets of four and find a mistake it were made. Live grouping is exactly what I had on my mind, which can be achieved with four styled input boxes, but that’s just another hack.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this

```
 <input id="cc" type="text" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999 9999 9999 9999'" />
```

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Your `data-inputmask` field requires script to do the enhancement.