Formatting a form input field
How can you format a form input field such that it only accepts numbers from users, takes a maximum of 16 digits, and adds a space after each four digits? I am trying to create a debit card such that the data a user enters in the form input fields are updated in real time on the card displayed by the side. And I want the card number to be arranged in fours, just as it is on a real card.
I tried saving the user input in a variable and then using a loop to insert a space after every four digits. Well, I don't know why but it didn't work.

as per the specific task you are trying to accomplish you may check here: How to Add space between every 4 characters in JavaScript? ... if you need specific help on your specific attempt you should instead share yours first so it can be addressed

https://www.peterbe.com/plog/cc-formatter

That should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534229/what-is-the-correct-input-type-for-credit-card-numbers

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I made a simple example using listeners and regular expressions.


const input = document.querySelector('input');
const show = document.querySelector('.card-number');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const cardNumber = input.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
  const formatted = cardNumber.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(' ');
  show.textContent = formatted;
});
.card-preview {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-number {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Card Number" maxlength="16">
  <div class="card-preview">
    <div class="card-number"></div>
    <!--<div class="card-number">XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX</div>-->
  </div>




You can add an event listener that uses regex that modifies the number input by the user:
JavaScript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const creditCardInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
  const formattedNumber = document.getElementById('displayedNumber');

  creditCardInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      let inputValue = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');      
      inputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 16);      
      let formattedValue = inputValue.replace(/(\d{4})(?=\d)/g, '$1 ');      
      e.target.value = formattedValue;
      formattedNumber.textContent = formattedValue;
  });
});

Minimal HTML page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example CC input formatter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="userInput">User Input:</label>
    <input type="text" id="userInput" maxlength="19">
    <p>Displayed Number (with formatting): <span id="displayedNumber"></span></p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


This solution has limit as 16 digits and formatting for each 4 chars


const cardNumberInput = document.getElementById('cardNumber');
const cardDisplay = document.getElementById('cardDisplay');

function formatCardNumber(input) {
  // Remove non-numeric characters
  let cardNumber = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

  // Limit to 16 digits
  if (cardNumber.length > 16) {
    cardNumber = cardNumber.slice(0, 16);
  }

  // Add space after every four digits
  cardNumber = cardNumber.replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  input.value = cardNumber;
  cardDisplay.textContent = cardNumber;
}

cardNumberInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  formatCardNumber(this);
});
<label for="cardNumber">Card Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="cardNumber" maxlength="19" placeholder="Enter your card number">

<div id="cardDisplay"></div>



